# SENDKEYS Statement fails to execute

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following procedure as part of the OnTime Method:

```
Public Sub Countdown()
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

The idea here is to close the workbook, once certain time period elapses; and should the workbook be in an edit mode, the "SendKeys ("{ESC}")" statement should de-activate editing mode. THE PROBLEM IS it does not do that! Once I manually press the "ESC" button, only then does my procedure run.
I would greatly appreciate if you could help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

UPDATE:
Following @Jeeped recommendation, I have updated the code above by adding the `DoEvents` line:

```
Public Sub Countdown()        
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")
    DoEvents
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

What I have noticed is that this procedure works (while in the editing mode) only if I manually run it by simply pressing the created form control button.
Why it is not run as part of the code is something I cannot understand.

Comment: The problem is that `OnTime` procedures won't run while you're in edit mode, so it's Catch22.

Comment: @Rory, thank you for bringing this up to me. I had no idea about it! And I'm so fed up with these Catch 22 things...) 
Is there any walk-around way you are aware of?

Comment: You'll need Windows Timers - something like the code posted by Jaafar here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/392397-problems-running-clock-worksheet-cell.html#post1956353

Comment: @Rory, thank you very much! Do you happen to have a saved demo file offered by Jaafar? The one on the webpage is unavailable...
Btw, I have already come across something very similar:
http://www.tmehta.com/tmxl/dbfind_byid.asp?id=8

Comment: @Rory, by the way, I have almost forgotten about the fact that your reply is, perhaps, the answer to my question. If you post as an answer, I will mark it as such. Thank you again for your insight!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need to allow an application to process its **message queue**. Stick a `DoEvents` between the `SendKeys ("{ESC}")` and the `ThisWorkbook.Close False`.

```
Public Sub Countdown()
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")
    DoEvents
    ThisWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and recommendation to use DoEvents. Unfortunately, this does not help me resolve the issue. I still cannot make my procedure auto-press the "ESC" button to de-activate the editing mode...

Comment: In that case, it may be simply that (by design) 'code won't run' from any inside process. This is indicated by the `ThisWorkbook`. Schedule it to run as an independent VBS WScript from VBA before the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks again! I have to admit, though, that I don't really know what VBS WScript is and would appreciate any details on how to implement that in my procedure.

Comment: If Excel is in edit mode, I'm not sure that VbScript would work either. Excel is pretty much "blocked" when in edit mode. But maybe @Jeeped has experience of it working ok.